# 'max-overlaps' issue in py-faster-rcnn

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am trying to run [py-faster-rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) on my own dataset following the tutorial.
But it is giving me **'Max_overlaps'** issue. While over going through other issues reported in that repository, i found out out that it may arise if foreground or background roi's are missing.
The format of Annotation file is exactly the same as mentioned here: 
1 200 200 360 345
while '1' being class name. and other values are x1,y1,x2 and y2 respectively.
Can anyone please point out that what can possibly cause this error?

```
File "./tools/train_net.py", line 112, in 
max_iters=args.max_iters)
File "/usr/local/caffes/xlw/faster-rcnn-third/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 155, in train_net
roidb = filter_roidb(roidb)
File "/usr/local/caffes/xlw/faster-rcnn-third/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 145, in filter_roidb
filtered_roidb = [entry for entry in roidb if is_valid(entry)]
File "/usr/local/caffes/xlw/faster-rcnn-third/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 134, in is_valid
overlaps = entry['max_overlaps']
KeyError: 'max_overlaps'
```

Comment: The link of tutorial is as follows: http://sgsai.blogspot.com/2016/02/training-faster-r-cnn-on-custom-dataset.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can occur if there already exists a cache file of all ROIs which might not correspond to the current dataset. Try deleting the .pkl file inside py-faster-rcnn/data/cache folder.